# Unable to reference other JS code after migrating Parse

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

After migrating from Parse.com to Parse Server on Heroku, I am unable to run cloud-code like this:

```
 var foo = require('cloud/test.js')
```

Before switching, this worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out:

```
 require('./test.js')
```

is the correct way to do this (due to server on heroku being linux based, as I was told)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the 'cloud/' part. If your js files are in the same directory, you should not need to include it. Doing so was a Parse thing.

Comment: Maybe just the cloud? So require('/test.js') ?

Comment: Still nothing. Tried that and a few other variations. If you have any other ideas keep shooting.

Comment: regardless of what I do, when it gets to the require line, I receive this error in Xcode:
2016-03-02 16:22:31.637 Foresight Team[58237:4357634] [Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=1 "{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}" UserInfo={error={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, NSLocalizedDescription={"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}, code=1})

Comment: Is this file in the same folder as your main.js?

Comment: yes. code for the test example is 
exports.hi = "hello"